# How i can send a WAP push message?

Tags: android, message

Hi
i am not able to send a WAP push message from my android phone. How i can push a WAP message to other phone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Capability to send WAP push messages is not available as an application on the phones. If the phone can be connected as a modem to PC consider using tools like NowSMS (www.nowsms.com) for sending push messages to other phones.

Comment: which one i have to use nowsms or nowwap? can i run nowsms/nowwap in ubutu also ,right?

Comment: Don't know about ubuntu, but trial version is available for windows, check the site.